# Fazer treinamento utilizando TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Estou com uma dúvida sobre Tensorflow.
Eu tenho alguns arquivos em csv que eu preciso fazer treinamento, mas quando eu vou ver a documentação do tensorflow, existem varias opções no train, não sei qual utilizar.

Alguém poderia dar um caminho de como posso realizar o treinamento?

Comment: Bem vindo Maick Henrique. Antes de mais nada você precisa saber o que vai fazer com os dados. Cada metodo que existe se encaixa para um tipo de situação. Descreva melhor esse csv, o que você pretende fazer. Outra coisa é visitar também a comunidade de Inteligência Artificial (https://ai.stackexchange.com/). Abraço!

Comment: Estou estudando qual o melhor framework para fazer um sistema de recomendação. Então eu tenho esse csv que são dados de clientes, todos em números, a partir disso eu preciso fazer um train para eles. Não sei se ficou muito claro. Obrigado

Comment: Entendi, mas seria melhor você editar o tópico adicionando essas informações e também um exemplo com poucos dados para entendermos o cenário. Abraços!